# Sanitizing user input for a message box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am developing a crypto-related application and since those people who deal in crypto will always try some sort of scam or script kiddie "hack" I'd like to figure out the best way to clean up content in user-to-user chat boxes and comments fields.

I don't want any HTML/CSS/JS in there.

I want to leave email addresses, URLs, phone numbers and "normal" text untouched.

Right now I am doing a `.gsub(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\@\;\:\-\_\,\.\ ]/i, '')` before_save but it removes the newlines.

I tried adding `.gsub(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\R\@\;\:\-\_\,\.\ ]/i, '')` to make it leave newlines alone but it does not seem to work.

Would prefer not having to add any gems.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: You don't need to escape *every* character in a set. `[^0-9a-zA-Z\@\;\:\-\_\,\.\ ]` is the same as `[^0-9a-zA-Z@;:_,. -]` (note the hyphen `-` is at the end so that it doesn't interpret it as a range). As another note `\w` matches `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, thus you can actually shorten your set to `[^\w@;:,. -]`

Comment: Rather than trying to sanitise every user input, I'd advise instead focusing on where the security **actually** matters - e.g. Not allowing SQL injections or XSS attacks. Sanitising a few random inputs like this probably won't make a difference; this is not where your security focus should be made.

Comment: Tom, the application does not use interpolation or concatenation on any data that is used in queries. This is about some "comments" or "message text" or "user description" fields where people may try to post a <script> tag. The regex above will break it but some things may still go through. I'd like to simply remove everything that "doesn't belong", but without forcing people to use email AT domain DOT com for emails or USD 1500 instead of $1500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has an excellent sanitizer built in, that I would recommend you use instead of trying to figure out your own regular expressions.

See:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Before you render any user's input out the page wrap it in `santize`

```
<%= sanitize @comment.body %>
```

If you want to sanitize before saving to the database, you can include the helper into your controller

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper

  def create
    content = sanitize(params[:content])
    Thing.save(content: content)
  end
end
```

Comment: can this go inside the model? I'd like to keep my controllers as thin as possible.

Comment: Sanitizing user input it more of a controller concern but there's nothing stopping you from including the helpers in a model.